# Only show similar questions related to my tags

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, user-interface

I noticed that questions not related to my tags are shown.

e.g. I wrote this question with tag [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), but the first similar question is about python.

> [image]

Comment: That question is just an example, right? Not an actual question you were going to ask?

Comment: [There is an old FR on uber meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213672/update-suggestions-when-asking-a-question-using-tags). Pretty sure I saw this here in MSO at some point, but can't find it right now...

Comment: @yivi, yes an incomplete question which I was about to write but then noticed the problem and made a screenshot.

Comment: @Black: I guess what yivi meant is that your question is for sure a duplicate. When you enter your question title to google, then at least 10 SO questions with the same problem show up. For example: [php replace first occurrence of string from 0th position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598665/php-replace-first-occurrence-of-string-from-0th-position)

Comment: @BDL, there are many ways to formulate a question, I did not searched it over google. I trusted the similar questions

Comment: Yeah, don't trust the SO search. It is notoriously broken. On SO at least a minimum of research is expected and this includes (at least) googling for your problem before asking a new question.