# Feature Request: Show tags on proposed similar questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, similar-questions

When creating a new question, it would be helpful to show the tags of the proposed similar questions. The title may be similar but the context may not. Please give some in the list already by showing the tags.

Can be loaded asynchronously or even via additional user interaction.

This improves on [Help askers find duplicates before the question becomes public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253339) and is related to, and complements [Only show similar questions related to my tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390881).

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [Show tags in "Similar questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337935/show-tags-in-similar-questions)